# Solr - Unknown field name when posting

Tags: java, json, solr

I'm trying to post a json to solr and keep getting this error...this is a custom field.

Command being used: java -Dtype=application/json -jar post.jar convertcsv1.json

The "books.json" example shown here works fine: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateJSON

Error back:

```
SimplePostTool version 1.5
Posting files to base url http://localhost:8983/solr/update using content-type          application/json..
POSTing file convertcsv1.json
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #400 Bad Request
SimplePostTool: WARNING: IOException while reading response: java.io.IOException: Server      returned HTTP response code: 40
0 for URL: http://localhost:8983/solr/update
1 files indexed.
COMMITting Solr index changes to http://localhost:8983/solr/update..
```

Answer (score -1):

If you do not add a required field to your post you get 400 Bad request error for missing required field. For an exact answer you should show logs of Solr under log folder at Solr home.

Answer (score -2):

If you want just post something on solr you can use a post plugin like Postman on chrome.

[Postman Rest Client.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client-packa/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop)

You have to post on this url (use the commit=true param to commit the objects)

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/update/json?commit=true
```

The content of your post have to be an array json.

```
[
 {..content..},
 {..content2..}
]
```

Reference

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateJSON